# Example of duck typing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, duck-typing

Is `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` an example of duck typing in action?

Is this also known as `behavioral typing`?

Comment: Yes, one could say so. `slice` takes everything that has a `.length` property ("*quacks like an array*" iykwim)

Comment: Not to me, it's creating an Array from an *arguments* object. Duck typing would be trying to detect if *obj* is an Array using something like `if (typeof obj.slice == 'function') /*obj is an array*/`.

Comment: @RobG: I meant that `Array::slice` uses duck typing internally